# programmatically add dependentAssembly to runtime\assemblyBinding

Tags: c#, dom, xml-namespaces

I am trying to add a new dependentAssembly to my Web.config file at run time. So far my current code has

```
    XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager (WebConfigDoc.NameTable);
    manager.AddNamespace("bindings", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1");

    XmlNode root = WebConfigDoc.DocumentElement;

    XmlNode assemblyBinding = root.SelectSingleNode("//bindings:assemblyBinding", manager);          

    XmlNode newAssemblyBinding = WebConfigDoc.ImportNode(GetElement(MyNewNode()), true);

    assemblyBinding.AppendChild(newAssemblyBinding);    
}

private string MyNewNode()
{    
    string Node = "<dependentAssembly>" +
                  "<assemblyIdentity name=\"newone\" "+
                  " publicKeyToken=\"608967\" />" +
                  "<bindingRedirect oldVersion=\"1\" newwVersion=\"2\" />" +
                  "</dependentAssembly>";
    return Node ;  
}
```

This works but the result node is this

```
<dependentAssembly xmlns="">
    <assemblyIdentity name="newone" publicKeyToken="608967" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1" newVersion="2" />
 </dependentAssembly>
```

I dont need the `xmlns=""` attribute to be appended.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and a complete and easy solution.

Comment: You asked *Is there a better way to do this?* Besides @Dimitre correct answer, I think XSLT suits better for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why its not working could be the XML serializer. The name space is right since the XmlNode assemblyBinding  object is not null and the code I have specified is what I am doing and nothing more. It might be becasue of the GetElement method which creates XmlNode from a string and return a new document element.

```
private static XmlElement GetElement(string xml)
        {
            //convert string to xml element
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);
            return doc.DocumentElement;
        }
```

I have anyway achieved the result using XPathNavigator. My final version.

```
XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager (WebConfigDoc.NameTable);
        manager.AddNamespace("bindings", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1");

        XmlNode root = WebConfigDoc.DocumentElement;


XPathNavigator assemblyBinding = root.CreateNavigator().
                                                 SelectSingleNode("//bindings:assemblyBinding", manager);

               assemblyBinding.AppendChild(MyNewNode());

private string MyNewNode()
{

   string Node = "<dependentAssembly>" +
                                      "<assemblyIdentity name=\"newone\" "+
                                      " publicKeyToken=\"608967\" />" +
                                      "<bindingRedirect oldVersion=\"1\" newwVersion=\"2\" />" +
                                    "</dependentAssembly>";
            return Node ;  
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because the new node you are adding is in "no namespace" while the parent is in the "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" namespace.

**Solution**:

**Change**:

```
  string Node = "<dependentAssembly>" +
```

**to**:

```
  string Node = "<dependentAssembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1'>" +
```

Comment: dependentAssembly should not have a xmlns attribute the node should look like

Comment: <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="newone" publicKeyToken="608967" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1" newVersion="2" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: I have tried above solution but i get node like    <dependentAssembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1'>

Comment: @firebrand: If the child and parent are both in the same namespace, the XML serializer *may* not show the namespace of the child. This is a question of XML serialization and you are unlucky if your XML serializer produces such output. However, I suspect that the namespace you provided isn't really the one that is used for the `assemblyBinding` element. Or you didn't "try" well? Also, note that this is not an xpath question at all.